# Nvidia driver for linux can't find kernel.h file

Tags: linux-kernel

I know my kernel.h file is in /usr/include/linux/
but this Nvidia program can't find it
then it asks me to run it with the --kernel-source-path argument
and I do give it that path and it doesn't work
It says it can't find it because it won't take the right path
Running it just by

`./nvidia.run`

Returns:

`ERROR: Unable to find the kernel source tree for the currently running

         kernel.  Please make sure you have installed the kernel source files

         for your kernel and that they are properly configured; on Red Hat

         Linux systems, for example, be sure you have the 'kernel-source' or

         'kernel-devel' RPM installed.  If you know the correct kernel source

         files are installed, you may specify the kernel source path with the

         '--kernel-source-path' command line option.`

And then running it by

`./nvidia.run --kernel-source-path /usr/include/linux/`

Returns:

`ERROR: The kernel header file '/usr/include/linux//include/linux/kernel.h'

         does not exist.  The most likely reason for this is that the kernel

         source path '/usr/include/linux/' is incorrect.  Please make sure you 
         have installed the kernel source files for your kernel and that they

         are properly configured; on Red Hat Linux systems, for example, be

         sure you have the 'kernel-source' or 'kernel-devel' RPM installed.

         If you know the correct kernel source files are installed, you may

         specify the kernel source path with the '--kernel-source-path'

         command line option.`

My first thought was to remove /include/linux/ from the address
but telling it to go to path /usr/ just told me it's invalid.
The kernel.h file really is in /usr/include/linux/kernel.h
but I can't get it to read it.

`ERROR: The kernel source path '/usr/' is invalid.  Please make sure you have 
         installed the kernel source files for your kernel and that they are

         properly configured; on Red Hat Linux systems, for example, be sure

         you have the 'kernel-source' or 'kernel-devel' RPM installed.  If you 
         know the correct kernel source files are installed, you may specify

         the kernel source path with the '--kernel-source-path' command line

         option.`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I'm sorry, should I move this there or can an admin move/delete this?

Comment: Click on flag and ask a mod to move it.

Comment: Done, this should be automatic, no?

Comment: If the moderator agrees with the migration, yes.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=843914, you can try

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```